# Cast and instance of in scala view template in playFramework

Tags: java, scala, templates, view, playframework

I am looping over collection of `Person` in scala view in PlayFramework2.2.6.
`Person` class is superclass for classes `User`,`Contact`.

While looping I would like to access some parameters specified for extending classes like `email` attribute in `User` class.

Here is model's classes:

```
public class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
  Date date;
}
public class User extends Person {
  String email;
  String login;
  String password;
}
public class Contact extends Person {
  Address address;
}

public class Customer {
  List<Person> persons;


  // AND NOW I WOULD LIKE TO DO THIS IN SCALA TEMPLATE


  public void print() {
    for(Person person: this.persons) {
      if(person instanceof User) {}
        System.out.println(((User)person).email);
      }
  }
}
```

view layer:

```
@for(person <- persons) {
  @if(person instanceOf User) {
     @((User)person).email
  }
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
value instanceOf is not a member of models.Person
```

Please give me some help on:

- how to cast variable to specified type
- how to verify type/instance of variable

in Scala template/view layer of PlayFramework.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scala/Twirl equivalents should be:

To verify instance type:

```
person.isInstanceOf[User] // bool?
```

To cast:

```
person.asInstanceOf[User] // User instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern matching:

```
@for(person <- persons) {
  @person match {
    case _ : User => {@{_.email}}  
    case _ => {@{}}
  }
}
```

This will look cleaner if you ever need to make an "If type of Contact" condition